# integrating javascript file, with html - simple example

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to integrate a simple html, js, and css file:

like this example on this link: [jsfiddle.net/MHDhT](http://jsfiddle.net/MHDhT)

I can link no problem to the css file like this (in the head tag):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
```

but then I dont know how to link to the js file, and Im not sure If just having the js content I can see on that link is enough ??

can someone help me ?

Comment: the js fiddle (seems) to work perfectly fine to me. What exactly is your problem? you are very unspecific

Comment: `<script src="src.js"></script>`

Comment: Also it uses jQuery which you need to include before your script.

Comment: @Zenith - put that in an answer so he can accept it

Comment: I have a directory with 3 files...html, css, and js, but I dunno if what I need to put inside the js file is only what is on the fiddle link, and how to link from the html to the website...

Comment: @JustAnil: You don't need to specify the type of the script, since `text/javascript` is the default type for scripts since... Netscape.

Comment: @MMM I knew this was the case for HTML 5, but unsure about xhtml & other doc types, looks like you are correct!.. thanks!.. learn something new everyday!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your js shoul be place **on the end of your page** for loading performance. (Like that the browser can start to render the web-page before the js has finished to load). But only if your Js is not mandatory for your Dom to load (it should be the case)

### you can link them in two differents ways:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   //Here is your code
</script>
```

### OR

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="url_of_your_js.js"></script>
```

### EDIT

Be sure to include jquery:

```
<head>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

If your code require the dom to be ready to be executed your should use

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //This is executed when dom is ready
});
```

The final result shoul look like this: (I put all In 1 file to be easier for you)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type"text/css">
              .menu { 
              background: #3B6997;
              font-weight: bold;
              padding: 10px;
              width: 300px;
              display:none;
              }
              .menu a {
              color: white;
              }
              .hov {
              width: 300px;   
              }

    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.hov').hover(function() {
                $('.menu').slideDown();
            }, function() {
                $('.menu').slideUp();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="hov">
        <a href="#">Activate Menu vv</a>

        <ul class="menu">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Item</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you want to put yout js in separate file, let's say 'app.js', put this in this file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.hov').hover(function() {
        $('.menu').slideDown();
    }, function() {
        $('.menu').slideUp();
    });
});
```

You link it by putting this on your head section :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
```

Comment: Strange, I cannot make it work...In the head tag I put this:
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="file.js"></script>

Comment: in the file.js:

$('.hov').hover(function(){
  $('.menu').slideDown();
},function(){
  $('.menu').slideUp();
});

Comment: @javardo you must have forgot the $(document).ready(function() {});

Comment: thanks, it works. But what it I want the js in a separate file ?
I'm not sure, if I'm not linking correctly to it, or it's content is not correct...

Comment: thank you very much for your help....In fact I dont know what I did wrong cause I think I had the same thing, but I copied your solution and it works...maybe I had some typo or something. Anyways thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

In JSFiddle you no need to specify these html, head, external css or js tags.  But in your .html it is must.
The [script](http://www.mkyong.com/javascript/how-to-link-an-external-javascript-file/) tag is used for linking a javascript file.

```
<html>
        <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/folderpath/style.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/folderpath/filename.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: The `type` attribute is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

To insert a JavaScript into an HTML page, use the `<script>` tag in the .html file

```
<script>
   //Your js code here 
</script>
```

To include a separate file (.js), use :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="mycode.js"></script>
```

Comment: not working, it the html file I put inside the head tag: <script src="file.js"></script>

and then in the same directory theres the file.js with the exact code, of the link...but once I open the html in the browser it doesnt work like like in the example...